# Find the Average Frequency

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, average, python

The average frequency of a function $x(t)$ is defined as:

$$ \langle \omega \rangle = \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega \cdot | X(\omega) |^{2} d \omega  }{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} | X(\omega) |^{2} d \omega} $$

where $X(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. I want to avoid taking the Fourier transform, so instead, according to Leon Cohen in his book *Time Frequency Analysis*, I can compute the average frequency via:

$$ \langle \omega \rangle =  \frac{1}{j} \cdot \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   x^{\ast}(t)  \cdot   \frac{\partial }{\partial t} x(t)   dt}{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^{2} dt }$$

When $x(t) = A(t) e^{j \phi(t)}$, this reduces to:

$$ \langle \omega \rangle = \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{d}{dt} \phi(t) \cdot A^{2}(t)  dt }{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^{2} dt }$$

Now I am trying to implement this in Python, but I am having no luck. I do not know what I am doing wrong, and wondering if anyone has any idea. My code is below -- (pieces stolen from around the internet):

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.signal as signal
import quadpy

def cosine_wave(f,fs,phase,num_cycles):
    t = numpy.arange(0,num_cycles*1/f-1/fs,1/fs) 
    g = numpy.cos(2*numpy.pi*f*t+phase) 
    return t,g 


def derivative(f,a,method='central',h=0.01):
    if method == 'central':
        return (f(a + h) - f(a - h))/(2*h)
    elif method == 'forward':
        return (f(a + h) - f(a))/h
    elif method == 'backward':
        return (f(a) - f(a - h))/h
    else:
        raise ValueError("Method must be 'central', 'forward' or 'backward'.")
    return

class signal_moment_calculator:

    def __init__(self, signal, time_samples, sampling_rate):
        self.signal = numpy.copy(signal)
        self.time = numpy.copy(time_samples)
        self.fs = numpy.copy(sampling_rate)
        self.signal_energy = integrate.simps(y=abs(self.signal)**2.0, x=self.time, dx=abs(self.time[1]-self.time[0]))
        self.signal_derivative = derivative(self.sample, time_samples, method='central', h = abs(time_samples[1] - time_samples[0]))

        self.signal_amplitude = abs(self.signal)
        self.signal_angles = numpy.unwrap(numpy.angle(self.signal)) 
        self.signal_angle_derivative = derivative(self.sample_angle, time_samples, method='central', h = abs(time_samples[1] - time_samples[0]))

    def sample(self, t_val):
        idx = []
        for t_v in t_val:
            idx.append(numpy.abs(self.time - t_v).argmin())     
        return numpy.asarray((self.signal[idx]))

    def sample_angle(self, t_val):
        idx = []
        for t_v in t_val:
            idx.append(numpy.abs(self.time - t_v).argmin())     
        return numpy.asarray((self.signal_angles[idx]))

    def mean_freq_calculator(self, t_val):
        idx = []
        for t_v in t_val:
            idx.append(numpy.abs(self.time - t_v).argmin())     
        return (1.0/1j) * numpy.conjugate(self.signal[idx]) * self.signal_derivative[idx]
        #return self.signal_angle_derivative[idx] * (abs(self.signal_amplitude[idx])**2.0)
        #return self.signal_angle_derivative[idx] * 2.0*(abs(self.signal_real[idx])**2.0)

    def calculate_freq_moments(self):
        mean,error = quadpy.quad(self.mean_freq_calculator, self.time[0], self.time[-1], epsabs=1e-4, epsrel=1e-4, limit=5000)
        mean /= self.signal_energy
        self.average_freq_ = mean
        return

#==============TEST===============#
freq = 1000
fs = 20*freq
num_cycles = 10
t_cos, x_cos = cosine_wave(freq,fs,0.0,num_cycles)
x_analytic = signal.hilbert(x_cos)

moment_calculator = signal_moment_calculator(x_analytic, t_cos, fs)
moment_calculator.calculate_freq_moments()
print("True Average Frequency: ", freq, "Average Frequency Calculated: ", moment_calculator.average_freq)
```

No matter what the frequency is, the sampling rate, or the number of cycles, or which of the three methods (that are commented out), the numbers are nowhere near each other.

**Questions:**

```
1. What am I doing wrong? 

2. Is there another (easier) way to calculate the average frequency without resorting to taking the Fourier transform?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the Fourier transform? FFT is computationally easy and multiplying by a variable is computationally easier than taking a derivative. As for what you're doing wrong, you forgot to take into account product rule.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Product rule? All the derivatives are calculated taking the complex nature of values into account. Could you explain? I want to avoid the FFT because it is being calculated by separate process that is often busy and therefore locks me out. I will instead do it in the time domain. In other words, this is a Python mockup of code for another system.

Comment: You calculated $x'(t)$ wrong

Comment: @NinadMunshi Do you mean that Scipy's Hilbert transform is not the correct thing to do?

Comment: No I mean the more basic derivative rule in your equations. $$x'(t) = j\phi'(t)A(t)e^{j\phi(t)} + A'(t)e^{j\phi(t)}$$ You didn't take this derivative correctly in your derivation of the time domain average frequency.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh okay -- I see. I will fix that --  But this still doesn't explain why it doesn't work when I just use the 'derivative' function.

Comment: Oh I see. I am not comfortable with the code so I didn't take a look, but one thing to keep in mind is that if you have a discrete time signal, the math is not a simple one-to-one from the continuous time equation to the discrete time counterpart. Once you have a sampled signal I would encourage you to look up the relevant literature on discrete time signals instead, because their frequencies are limited to the range $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see -- that is probably what I was doing wrong. I was counting on the fact that the support of the function is small in the frequency domain. So I need to think about this....

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well, the integral $\int_{-\frac{f_{s}}{2}}^{\frac{f_{s}}{2}} X_{samped}(f) df = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X_{continuous}(f) df$ when my signal is low pass, or my signal is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform $X(\cdot)$. So I dont think that is the problem unless the time domain calculation is implicitly adding up all the aliased parts of the spectrum...in which case, should I lowpass my signal? I can't actually get rid of those aliases, can I?